# How do I mass delete Territory2 records in Apex?

Tags: dml, dmlexception, territory-management, territory

I have a list of Territory2 records.  All of them are from the deepest level of my territory hierarchy.  When I attempt to save some apex to Salesforce that would delete this list of records, I'm presented with the error...

> DML operation Delete not allowed on List

I need to automate the deletion of these territories.  What are my best options for doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I mass delete Territory2 records in Apex?

You don't. You can use the REST or SOAP API, or an app like the Apex Data Loader, but a Territory isn't something you can automate directly in Apex Code. It's restricted because of the implications of doing this in something like a trigger, which could potentially cause sharing row locks when territories are quickly added or removed.